# Install Xmind on Centos 7

Tags: centos

I am trying to install `Xmind` on Centos 7. This is what I have tried:

```
Download Xmind with deb package
ar -x xmind-linux-3.31. . .-i368.deb
tar xvf data.tar.gz
cp -r usr/local/xmind/ /usr/local/
cp usr/share/mime/packages/xmind.xml /usr/share/applications
cp /usr/share/applications/xmind.desktop /usr/share/applications/
tar -zxvf control.tar.gz
chmod 755 postinst
./postinst
```

But when I try:

```
./postinst
```

I get this error:

```
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
```

Comment: You've downloaded the Debian version (which is understandable as it's the only version available for Linux). However, you can't simply extract the contents of a `deb` file and hope it works on any machine, let alone a non-`deb` system. Your best option would be to download the [portable version](http://www.xmind.net/download/portable/) and try that one.

Comment: Does converting the package with [alien](http://joeyh.name/code/alien/) work better? (I'm sure there's a CentOS package, if not in CentOS itself then on a popular third-party repository.)

Comment: I have installed successfully according to this url:
http://www.centoscn.com/image-text/install/2015/1010/6274.html Hope it helpful. :)